# convert one row/n-columns to multi-rows/3-columns python-pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I am trying to convert a single row multiple columns (.csv) to n-rowsx3columns and save it in a new file (csv or txt)

Data:

```
51.9596,-115.1437,6.0000,51.9596,-115.1285,6.0000,51.9686,-115.1588,6.0000,51.9686,-115.1437,10.5000,51.9686,-115.1285,10.5000,51.9686,-115.1134,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1891,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1740,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1588,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1437,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1285,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1134,8.0000,51.9866,-115.1891,7.0000
```

I want:

```
52.9596,-118.1437,6.0000
51.9596,-115.1285,6.0000
54.9686,-119.1588,6.0000
53.9686,-119.1437,10.5000
54.9686,-117.1285,10.5000
55.9686,-111.1134,8.0000
56.9776,-112.1891,7.5000
57.9776,-117.1740,7.5000
58.9776,-112.1588,7.5000
59.9776,-117.1437,8.0000
50.9776,-114.1285,8.0000
50.9776,-115.1134,8.0000
50.9866,-116.1891,7.0000
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('~\datatest\datatest2.csv', sep=',')
for i in len (0, len(df), 3):
   df1=df
df1.to_csv('~\datatest\out.csv', sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('~\datatest\datatest2.csv', 'r') as f:
    v = f.readline().split(',')

with open('~\datatest\out.csv', 'w') as f:
    for n in range(len(v)//3):
        f.write(','.join(v[n*3:(n+1)*3]) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

By what I understood, this should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('~\datatest\datatest2.csv', sep=',')

#reshaping your dataframe as an array and storing it in df2
df2 = df.values.reshape(int(len(df.columns)/3), 3)

#converting df2 (that's currently an array) to a dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2)

#exporting it
df2.to_csv(your_filepath, separator)
```

Comment: Thanks @helena-martins, but i received this error for the "df=2df.values.reshape" line CANNOT RESHAPE ARRAY OF SIZE 0 INTO SHAPE (63277,3)

Comment: There is a syntax error. It should be `df2 = df.values.reshape`. Try moving the 2 to the other side of the equation

Comment: the error is for this line "df2 = df.values.reshape(int(len(df.columns)/3), 3)"  CANNOT RESHAPE ARRAY OF SIZE 0 INTO SHAPE (63277,3)

Comment: According to the error, and considering you did exactly what I specified, your dataframe is most probably empty. Could you show the entire code, exactly the way it is now?

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('H:/datatest/datatest2.csv', sep=',')
df2 = df.values.reshape(int(len(df.columns)/3), 3)
f2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2)
df2.to_csv('H:/datatest/datatest2out.csv', sep=',')

Comment: Weird, it seems right to me. Could you show a little bit of your csv? I will try to reproduce this error

Comment: sorry Helena, the snippet is up there (too long). Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

```
linelist = '''51.9596,-115.1437,6.0000,51.9596,-115.1285,6.0000,51.9686,-115.1588,6.0000,51.9686,-115.1437,10.5000,51.9686,-115.1285,10.5000,51.9686,-115.1134,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1891,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1740,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1588,7.5000,51.9776,-115.1437,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1285,8.0000,51.9776,-115.1134,8.0000,51.9866,-115.1891,7.0000'''
linelist = linelist.split(',')
print(linelist)

col1 = [float(x)%1 for x in linelist]
col2 = [float(x)%2 for x in linelist]
col3 = [float(x)%3 for x in linelist]
print(col1,col2,col3)
datadict = {'col1':col1, 'col2':col2, 'col3':col3}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(datadict)
```